# Supervised or Unsupervised Clustering

Tags: clustering, supervised-learning

I have a set of N samples belong to K classes. I am using k-means clustering with Euclidean distance in order to cluster these samples into K clusters. To help the k-means algorithm to group samples of a specific class into one cluster, I initialized the k-means algorithm so that the mean value of each cluster is the mean value of the samples of a specific class.

My question is **not** about the usefulness of what I mentioned above or the purpose of it, however, my question is: 
In machine learning, is this called "supervised clustering", "semi-supervised clustering" or just "normal clustering initialized by means of samples of the real class"? I want to know the correct terminology when we use k-means initialized by real-class mean values.

Comment: Since you don't explicitly use label information, except for initial cluster centers, this is just traditional unsupervised clustering. Note that fully supervised clustering does not exist, that's classification.

Comment: Thanks @MarcClaesen. I am still wondering if the initital cluster centers that I use is considered as a "similarity adapting" method. If it is, then this is called "semi-supervised" clustering as mentioned in page 8 of http://cedric.cnam.fr/~crucianm/src/BriefSurveyClustering.pdf

Comment: No, I don't feel this satisfies tag "semi-supervised". Giving the starting cluster centres in K-means is arbitrary. The fact that you give them as "good" from some point of view does not affect the algorithm itself. The algorithm does not _know_ that you "meant" these starting values as a constraint. So, it is just "starting configuration", not "supervision over algorithm".

Comment: Thanks a lot @ttnphns. I see, that is now makes sense for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K-means is ''unsupervised'' by definition: it does not take the labels into account.

You however performed a ''supervised initialization''.

So I'd call this an unsupervised algorithm that has been initialized in a supervised manner.

And no, I don't think it makes a lot of sense to do it this way.